# Regex: Get all non-numeric characters except the first?

Tags: regex

So, essentially, I want to user regex to remove all excess expression characters in this string:

```
22*44++--**3333------33

// turn this into:

22*44+3333-33
```

If there is 1 expression, leave it. If there are multiple, just keep the first one.

The pattern is number then first expression then number etc.

Comment: If the string always starts with digits, you can also try a non-word boundary if supported: Search for [`\B\D+`](https://regex101.com/r/FQ3j2q/1) and replace with empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a substitution, replacing strings of non-digit characters with just the first of those:

Find: `(\D)\D+`
Replace with: `\1` (first capture group; in some regex flavors use `$1`)
Use global (`g`) modifier

See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CEyhVr/1)